# Matching mathematical operations in scala using regex

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to match mathematical operations using a match in scala. So the function will be able to match any string like "5+2" or "log10" or "10^5" etc. However the match keeps failing for the individual types of expressions

```
def isValid(expression:String):Boolean={

  val number = """((\-|\+)?[0-9]+\.?[0-9])*"""
  val operation = """([\+,\-,*,/,C,P])"""
  val functions = """(log|ln|sin|cos|tan|arc sin|arc cos|arc tan|sec|csc|cot)"""
  val powers = """\^"""+number

  val arithmeticExpression = (number + operation + number).r
  val functionExpression = (functions + number).r
  val powerOperation = (number + powers).r
  val stringToTest: Regex = ("""(""" +arithmeticExpression+"""|"""+functionExpression+"""|"""+powerOperation+""")""").r

  expression match {
      case arithmeticExpression(s) => true
      case functionExpression(s) => true
      case powerOperation(s)=>true
      case _ => false

  }
}


println(isValid("1+4").toString)
```

However if I match for a general expression I get the expected output:

```
  def isValid(expression:String):Boolean={
  val number = """(\-|\+)?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*"""
  val operation = """[\+,\-,*,/,C,P]"""
  val functions = """(log|ln|sin|cos|tan|arc sin|arc cos|arc tan|sec|csc|cot)"""
  val power = """\^"""+number
  val arithmeticExpression = number+operation+number
  val functionExpression = functions+number
  val powerExpression = number+power

    val validExpression = """(""" +arithmeticExpression+"""|"""+functionExpression+"""|"""+powerExpression+""")"""
    validExpression.r.findFirstIn(expression) match {
      case Some(`expression`) => true
      case None => false
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing numbers correctly:

```
scala> arithmeticExpression.findFirstIn("1+4")
res2: Option[String] = Some(+)                     

scala> arithmeticExpression.unapplySeq("1+4")
res3: Option[List[String]] = None

scala> arithmeticExpression.unapplySeq("11+14")
res4: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(11, null, +, 14, null))
```

Since you're requiring two digits.

Comment: There are websites for trying out regexes, which are painful to look at and compose. It would be nice if there were a library you could load in the REPL to pull apart regexes, etc. Also, use `case r(_*) =>` to ignore matching groups if you're not interested in them.

Comment: Yep the parenthesis messed up the expression. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "()" in the regular expression for numbers was affecting the result. Also /^ needed to wrapped in (). This ended up working for me.

```
def isValid(expression:String):Boolean={
  val number = """[\-,\+]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*"""
  val operation = """([\+,\-,*,/,C,P])"""
  val functions = """(log|ln|sin|cos|tan|arc sin|arc cos|arc tan|sec|csc|cot)"""
  val powers = """(\^)"""+number
  val arithmeticExpression = (""""""+number + operation + number+"""""").r
  val functionExpression = (functions + number).r
  val powerOperation = (number + powers).r
  val stringToTest: Regex = ("""(""" +arithmeticExpression+"""|"""+functionExpression+"""|"""+powerOperation+""")""").r

  expression match {
      case arithmeticExpression(s) => {
        println("Arithmetic Match")
        true
      }
      case functionExpression(s) => {
        println("Function Match")
        true
      }
      case powerOperation(s)=>{
        println("Power Match")
        true
      }
      case _ => false

  }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't think your "number" RE is quit on.  It seems to allow for `,7.` (comma-digit-dot) as an acceptable number. Perhaps this is a bit closer to what's needed: `"""[-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?"""`

Comment: Thanks, I kinda thought the symbols in [] had to be comma separated